# Getting Error when Creating Gradle Project : Server returned HTTP response code: 403

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I want to create a gradle project on **Eclipse Luna** but when I enter the Name of project and select Sample project as

**Java API and Implementation**

It gives me an error as :

[image: Image Displaying the error at Eclipse window]

Please suggest me where I am wrong or what should I do to prevent it.

Remember, I want to create a project from begining in  Eclipse as a gradle project.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http://gradle.org website experienced some outtakes this morning that causes this issue. it should work again.

Comment: I think you are right...I will try again today with the same steps hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Eclipse and install the latest Gradle integration plugin

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0

Alternatively check you can physically download http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip